# Log4net and Domains

Tags: log4net

Здравствуйте

Использую log4net в WCF сервисе под IIS для ведения лога.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <log4net>
    <appender name="DMLogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\EDGE\DataService\Logs\" />
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd.\D\M.lo\g"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    </appender>
    <logger name="DataManipulation">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DMLogFile"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="SeriesComputation">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="DMLogFile"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Проявляется такая проблема. Результирующее имя файла, например

> 2014-01-20.DM.log

но в неопределенный момент могут появиться другие файлы, у которых имя просто дублируется:

> 2014-01-20.DM.log2014-01-20.DM.log
> 2014-01-20.DM.log2014-01-20.DM.log2014-01-20.DM.log

У программы есть особенность. Она создает несколько доменов и логирование идет из этих доменов в один и тот же файл. Таким образом есть предположение, что проблема в синхронизации:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
```

и в данном случае нужно применять InterProcessLock.

Народ. Поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста.